# Excel Macro: Print the value of a specific row with variable columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to print out a certain row based on a column that can be anything, and I was trying to use something like this:

```
'Gets me the Title(Top of Column) of whatever cell was changed
    If Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("A2").Value = "" Then

        Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("A2").Value = Range(Target.Column & ("7")).Value
    Else

        Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value =  Range(Target.Column & ("7")).Value
    End If
```

I thought using something similar to this would work as you see above in my code:

```
Range("H" & Target.Row)
```

which seems to work for that case, but when I try to do a specific row I get the error "Method Range of Object_Worksheet failed". Hopefully it's a very easy fix that I just don't know about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Range cannot be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891060/application-defined-or-object-defined-error-excel/24891699#24891699) with absolute row and column numbers use `Cells(Row,Column)` instead

```
Cells("7", Target.Column)
```

To get the  Address and Value of the changed cell, use 
`Target.Address` and `Target.Value` respectively

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize it was such a simple question. I always try to give as much detail as possible, but thanks for the advice. Definitely should have been simpler. Thanks for the help though. It worked.